# Any sample on integrating XMPP Server with play framework Using scala?

Tags: playframework, xmpp

I wanted to integrate XMPP chat for my Play framework web app. It should be kind of customer support chat window, the live chat window. Is there any documentation/sample available and which XMPP server should I choose to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use openfire for this, there is a plugin called fastpath that is meant for your requirement, see this link

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/fastpath/readme.html

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/webchat/readme.html

Comment: Thanks Jaspreet for the response.Will check this and get back to you.

Comment: You are welcome, please upvote if it helps you, so that others can see this lickly

Comment: Hi Jaspreet,1) Installed Openfire 3.9.3

2) Installed fastptah webchat plugin  (This was not working with available plugins. so, installed the war from OpenFire 3.7.0 - FastPath WebChat not installing? | Ignite Realtime )

3)Installed fastpath service plugin

4) webchat url - http://<host>:7070/webchat/   works fine.

5) Workgroup demo shows offline.

Do I need t install spark from http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/ to have the workgrpup online ?
Also, how will I embed spark UI into my play webapp ?

Comment: I used http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/fastpath/readme.html that need spark, I have not used web plugin, but the docs says what you need